# Sorting class instances in python

Tags: python, sorting

What does python 2.7 use to sort vanilla class instances? I'm interested in the default sorting behavior.

Suppose I have the class

```
class S():
    pass
```

Then I can create a couple of instances, and sort them:

```
a = S(); b = S(); c = S()
l = [(a,'a'), (b,'b') ,(c, 'c')]
sorted(l)
```

This will print some sorting of the objects. Now I have a two part question:

- Is python using the objects' `__hash__()`, and thus their `id()`?
- Is it possible to override `__hash__()` to influence the sorting behavior?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?  My impulse is "override __lt__, __gt__ etc" but I have spotty understanding of Python 2's "classic" classes so don't know if that's appropriate here.  You might also find this link helpful: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's sort algorithm exclusively compares items using a "less than" test, which can be implemented either using the `__cmp__()` special method (now deprecated) or `__lt__()` on the class.

In the absence of any specific instruction on how to compare two objects, the `id()` is used (not the hash) for objects of the same type, as in your case.

Answer (score 6):

Python 3's built-in sorting makes use of the `__lt__` method in your class.

The rich comparison methods are special in Python, since they can return a special `NotImplemented` type if there is not `__lt__` defined - take a look at the docs on this page: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Since the truth value of `NotImplemented` is `True`, any boolean comparison that gets `NotImplemented` will continue as if the first element actually is less than the second, which will cause the sort to leave the list in the same order as it was.

Take a look at the interactive shell. You can see how the truth values would be used in a sort, and that Python thinks that both objects are less than each other:

```
>>> class S():
...     pass
...
>>> a = S()
>>> b = S()
>>> a.__lt__( b )
NotImplemented
>>> if a.__lt__( b ):
...     print( "derp!" )
...
derp
>>> if b.__lt__(a):
...     print( "derp" )
...
derp
```

Here are some more references:

- [The __lt__ method (Unofficial Python Reference Wiki)](http://pyref.infogami.com/__lt__)
- [Sorting Mini How-To](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)
- [Built-In Constants](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html)

**EDIT:**
After taking a look at Python 2.7, it looks like the ID of the objects is used for sorting, and the `__lt__` method is undefined on a simple class like your example.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: But, the instances aren't left in their order! In my example I get `[b, c, a]`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I was missing the 2.7 angle (I've been using 3.2).  After some similar investigation in the interactive shell, it looks like the ID of the classes are actually used.  However, you can see how this behavior shouldn't be relied on, especially if you're going to migrate between versions of Python.

Comment: Relying on the default sort is what got me in trouble in the first place. Using `(value, object)` tuples to sort lists is very dangerous if python does a secondary sort on the object's id! I didn't know these kind of things had changed between python versions, I'm indeed using 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example on my own machine (python 2.7):

```
>>> sorted(l)
[(<__main__.S instance at 0x107142a70>, 'a'), (<__main__.S instance at 0x107142ab8>, 'b'), (<__main__.S instance at 0x107142b00>, 'c')]
```

Note that the sorted list is in order of the `id()`:

```
>>> id(a)
4413729392
>>> id(b)
4413729464
>>> id(c)
4413729536
```

If I generate the hashes I get:

```
>>> hash(a)
275858087
>>> hash(b)
-9223372036578917717
>>> hash(c)
275858096
```

Which suggests that the sorting is *not* based on the hash.

See derekerdmann's answer for information on how to make python sort your class the way you want.

**Edit:** By the way, if you put the items in the list in reverse and then sort it, you get:

```
>>> l = [(c,'c'), (b, 'b'), (a, 'a')]
>>> sorted(l)
[(<__main__.S instance at 0x107142a70>, 'a'), (<__main__.S instance at 0x107142ab8>, 'b'), (<__main__.S instance at 0x107142b00>, 'c')]
```

Once again, its sorted in order of the `id()`.

Comment: So they are not left in order as derek suggests. And actually, it says [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) that `__hash__` returns `id()` by default, how do you explain the difference?