# Python sorting class instance containing list with tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, class, sorting

This is exercise 18.2 from "Think Python" book. There is a Class called `Deck` that creates a deck of cards as a list of tuples `[(0,1), (0, 2)...]`. The class has defined inner functions `shuffle()` and `sort()`. The `shuffle()` function works correct but when I try to sort the deck the fuction `sort()` I wrote does not return sorted deck.

I have no idea why is that. Any hint what am I doing wrong?

```
class Deck(object):
    """Represents deck of cards
        attributes: list of cards
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for card in self.cards:
            res.append(str(card))
        return '\n'.join(res)

    def pop_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def sort(self):
        self.cards.sort()


new_deck = Deck()
print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>new deck:'
print new_deck

new_deck.shuffle()
print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>shuffled deck:'
print new_deck

new_deck.sort()
print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>sorted deck:'
print new_deck
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the definition of `Card` - also you are creating instances of `Card` instead of using `tuple`. The `sort()` function sorts tuples element-wise, using the next element one when a draw on the first happens:

```
[ (0,1),(0,-2) ].sort()
```

results in

```
[ (0,-2),(0,1) ] # because draw on (0,_)
```

For your `Card`'s class python does not know how to sort it, so it uses the `id()` function (unless you tell it how to sort itself, see below).

You can either define a `key` for your call to `sort(...)` or define `Card.__lq__()` method on your cards so it does *not* use `id()` when sorting cards:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    # fancier output
    s = {0:"hearts",1:"diamonds",2:"clubs",3:"spades"}
    r = {i:v for i,v in enumerate( [ "Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
                                     "9","10","Jack","Queen","King"],1)}
    def __init__(self, suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(Card.r[self.rank],Card.s[self.suit])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    # UNCOMMENT to not need the sort-key() in Deck
    # def __lt__(self,other):
    #    return (self.suit,self.rank) < (other.suit, other.rank)

class Deck(object): 
    # keep the rest of your code, fix this: 
    # or uncomment __lq__() in Cards (which would be the prefered 
    # way to do it) and leave your method as is
    def sort(self):
        # tell sort to sort based on what key 

        self.cards.sort(key = lambda x: (x.suit, x.rank))


new_deck = Deck()
print '# new deck:'
print new_deck

new_deck.shuffle()
print '# shuffled deck:'
print new_deck

new_deck.sort()
print '# sorted deck:'
print new_deck
```

Output (shortened):

```
# new deck:
Ace of hearts   ... up to ...  King of hearts
Ace of diamonds ... up to ...  King of diamonds
Ace of clubs    ... up to ...  King of clubs
Ace of spades   ... up to ...  King of spades

# shuffled deck:
6 of hearts
7 of spades
# ... snipp the remaining mixed cards ...
2 of hearts
King of diamonds

# sorted deck:
Ace of hearts   ... up to ...  King of hearts
Ace of diamonds ... up to ...  King of diamonds
Ace of clubs    ... up to ...  King of clubs
Ace of spades   ... up to ...  King of spades
```

See also:

- [Sorting class instances in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650401/sorting-class-instances-in-python) (mix of 2.7 and 3.x stuff)

Comment: Thank you very, very much Patrick for your reply. Indeed both of your solutions work perfectly. I have also tried to implement __cmp__ function instead of __lt__ within Card class and it works perfectly too with `self.cards.sort()`. However I also took a look at terryjbates repository [https://github.com/terryjbates/think-python/blob/master/chapter-18/exercise-18.2.py] and I can't figure out why in the sort function he inputs `self.cards.sort(cmp=Card.__cmp__)`. Is it pythonic to add this argument 'cmp=Card.__cmp__' within sort() function?

Comment: @halny normally you do not use the methods with `__dunder__()` directly  .. mostly you use len() instead of `__len__`, iter() instead of `__iter__()` etc.  the `__cmp__()` is a method he created on the card and when sorting the deck he tells the sort methdod to use that one for sorting - it is similar to the `key` in  `self.cards.sort(key = lambda x: (x.suit, x.rank))` - but that is the python3 sort function syntax. I am a bit rusty on 2.7. [`cmp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) is from python 2 - and got changed to the key-function

Comment: Essentially both are providing the "What to use for sorting function" to the list.sort(...) method